# Remove superfluous punctuation from strings in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

hi I have a dataframe as below

df1:-

```
rade   volume    packitt 
wear   28        cult,,daok
kwat   45        vaner ,boera
itre   17        eaker, ewlvwe, The wrerin
reww   87     
hakw   57        ,rabe,,boera
kryh   45        vaner ,boera,vanya,
```

now I want to remove extra commas

Output dataframe

```
rade   volume    packitt 
wear   28        cult,daok
kwat   45        vaner,boera
itre   17        eaker,ewlvwe,The wrerin
reww   87 
hakw   57        rabe,boera
kryh   45        vaner,boera,vanya
```

Comment: What code have you tried? You need to give us the code that you attempted first.

Comment: How did you get this data? Using `apply(' ,'.join)`? You can fix that code to prevent this output.

Answer (score 2):

This was likely caused by improper column-wise aggregation of strings (did you mean to do something like `df.agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)`?).

However, for reference, you can remove commas using a non-regex solution involving `str.split` and `str.join`:

```
df['packitt'] = [
    ','.join(filter(None, x.split(','))) if pd.notna(x) else x 
    for x in df['packitt']
]

df
   rade  volume                    packitt
0  wear      28                  cult,daok
1  kwat      45               vaner ,boera
2  itre      17  eaker, ewlvwe, The wrerin
3  reww      87                       None
4  hakw      57                 rabe,boera
5  kryh      45         vaner ,boera,vanya
```

---

Or, using pandas column string operations `str.replace` (with regex) + `str.strip`:

```
df['packitt'] = df.packitt.str.replace(r'(\s*,\s*)+', ',').str.strip(',')

df
   rade  volume                  packitt
0  wear      28                cult,daok
1  kwat      45              vaner,boera
2  itre      17  eaker,ewlvwe,The wrerin
3  reww      87                     None
4  hakw      57               rabe,boera
5  kryh      45        vaner,boera,vanya
```

Where `r'(\s*,\s*)+'` will match 1 or more commas surrounded by 0 or more spaces.

Comment: I think as OP want to remove the spaces, too,the regex part should be `...replace(' *,+ *', ',')...`, no?

Comment: @coldspeed , can you please explain what is happening between `(\s*,\s*)` and `(\s*,\s*)+` ?

Comment: @pyd It will match one or more commas optionally separated by spaces. So `,,`, `, ,`, `, , ,`, `,,    ,,    ,,` etc are all valid matches (even though not explicitly required by OP).